# What about Power Functions motor, S size?

Tags: technic, power-functions, motor

LEGO Power Functions has motors in [M](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58120c01#T=C), [L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99499c01#T=C) and [XL](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58121c01#T=C) sizes. Usually, if someone uses this size designations, the smallest one is S. It would make sense to have them named S, M and L if there were meant to be only 3.

Now, for my personal "rebuild, restore" project, I'd need something a bit smaller than [M](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58120c01#T=C), to go with my old sets. Is there any S size power function motor? Was there? Was planned, but cancelled? Any official or semi-official info on it?

Comment: There's also E (https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87577c01&idColor=86#T=C&C=86) and the servo motor (https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=110903#T=C), and I think there's at least one more variant that I can't remember, but at least the two varaiants that I do remeber aren't smaller than M.

Comment: @Henrik E is the same size as M (6 x 4 x 3) and servo is, well, servo.

Comment: The E motor is better used as a generator than an actual motor. No benefits compared to a M motor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only in 2012 the L-motor was released. The M and XL motors where released in 2007. That is a gap of 5 years where people were even more confused about the size options...

Anyway, no smaller motor with power functions

However if you are willing to go with the 9V system (possibly with conversion cables), there's the mini and micro motor, standard motor is also a bit smaller in length.

More info here:
http://www.philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm

Answer (score 4):

As far as we know, no other motor sizes were planned. It's possible they were named this way to allow for future expansions, like when the L motor was added.

It's worth noting that it's unlikely we will see any new motors come out for the current Power Function system, as Power Functions 2.0 was just recently announced at the Nuremberg Toy Fair and features the Boost connectors.